# Serialize XML to a class with a different name

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

Lets say I've got an API response that looks like this

```
<ApiException>
    <Status>400</Status>
    <Message>Foot too big for mouth</Message>
<ApiException>
```

I know how to create a class called `ApiException` and serialize to that:

```
public class ApiException
{
    public string Status { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

using (var response = ((HttpWebResponse)wex.Response))
{
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer serializer =
            new System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer(typeof(ApiException));
        ApiException ex = (ApiException)serializer.Deserialize(reader);
    }
}
```

And I also know how to specify Element names for my properties

```
public class ApiException
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(ElementName = "Status")]
    public string Whut { get; set; }
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElement(ElementName = "Message")]
    public string Why { get; set; }
}
```

But what if I already have a class called `ApiException`? Say I want to call this one `FootMouthAPIException`

Is there any way to do that? Maybe an Data Annotation on the class itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [XmlRoot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlrootattribute%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) attribute, e.g.

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "ApiException")]
public class FootMouthAPIException
{
}
```